# Are infinite loops possible in the game Prodway?

Tags: grid-deduction, board-games

I'd like to know if infinitely repeating sequences of moves (i.e. cycles) are possible in the following game:

> [Prodway](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/3130103/new-orthogonal-connection-games-reneo-prodway-and) is a game for two players (Black and White) that is
> played on an initially empty square board. The top and bottom edges of
> the board are colored black; the left and right edges are colored
> white.
>
> A *crosscut* is a 2x2 area containing two diagonally adjacent black
> stones and two diagonally adjacent white stones.
>
> Black plays first, then turns alternate. On your turn, place a stone
> of your color on an empty point or on a point occupied by an enemy
> stone. In the latter case, move the enemy stone to an orthogonally
> adjacent empty point before placing your stone. Your newly placed
> stone must not be part of any crosscuts. If the moved enemy
> stone is part of one or more crosscuts, remove the other enemy stones
> in those crosscuts.
>
> You win if, after a full move by either player, there is a chain of
> orthogonally connected stones of your color touching the two opposite
> board edges of your color. Passing is not allowed, but, if you have no
> legal moves available, your turn is skipped.

Here's a mesmerizing near cycle (ignoring the win condition):

[image: Near cycle in Prodway.]

Reneo, a related game, is [finite](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121881/are-infinite-loops-possible-in-the-game-reneo), but has different rules for swaps and removals. In Prodway, captures are more frequent, and you can capture up to two enemy stones on a single turn. In Reneo, you never capture more than one stone on a single turn.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455347/are-infinite-loops-possible-in-the-game-prodway